# Efficiently Filtering a Nested Array

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, algorithm

I have a large data set in the form of an array:

```
[
        {
            id: '9',
            name: 'Foo',
            nestedTypes: [
                {
                    value: '10025',
                    displayValue: 'Request value A',
                },
                {
                    value: '10027',
                    displayValue: 'Some random request',
                },
            ],
        },
        {
            id: '3',
            name: 'Name B',
            nestedTypes: [
                {
                    displayValue: 'Bar',
                    value: '10026',
                },
                {
                    displayValue: 'Another request within B',
                },
            ],
        },
    ]
```

I need to construct a flattened array of objects from this dataset after running a text-match. Given a string, if it appears in the value of the key 'name', the parent object along with all its 'nestedTypes' is included in result. In case it does not appear, I need to search for a match in 'displayValue' in 'nestedTypes'. If there's a match, it gets included in the flattened array along with its parent.

Eg. search string 'Foo', result:

```
[{
  label:'Foo',
  value:9 

}, {
  value: '10025',
  label: 'Request value A'
}, {
  value: '10027',
  label: 'Some random request'
}]
```

Search string : 'Bar', result:

```
[{
  label:'Name B',
  value:3 

}, {
  value: '10026',
  label: 'Bar'
}]
```

The data set is huge - array of about 500 with around 7 'nestedTypes'.

I am doing this in a two-step process using Array.reduce:

```
 const flattenGroupedTypes = (groupedTypes, filterString) => {
        const constructed = groupedTypes.reduce((acc, current) => {
                if (current.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterString.toLowerCase())) {
                    return acc.concat([
                        {
                        label:current.name,
                        value:current.id
                        },
                        ...current.nestedTypes.map(nestedType => ({label:nestedType.displayValue, value:nestedType.value})),
                    ]);
                }
                const nestedTypesMatched = current.nestedTypes.filter(type => type.displayValue.toLowerCase().includes(filterString.toLowerCase()));
                if (nestedTypesMatched.length) {
                    return acc.concat([
                        {
                        label:current.name,
                        value:current.id
                        },
                        ...nestedTypesMatched.map(nestedType => ({label:nestedType.displayValue, value:nestedType.value})),
                        ),
                    ]);
                }
                return acc;
            },
            []
        );
        return constructed;
    };
```

Can I make this efficient? I can't seem to find a better algorithm/way of reducing computation or making it simpler. This matters to me because I am dealing with could be large.

Comment: To make it efficient you have to remove all `filter`, `include`, `map`, ... A simple `for` loop is up to 10 times faster than these array functions.

Comment: Your results don't match your description of what you said you wanted. You said "the original object" is included in the results, but it isn't in the results shown, and you've created an object with a property called `label` that you didn't mention anywhere. What do you really want here?

Comment: All you need here is a loop. `for-of` is usually fine (they're aggressively optimized), but if you run into a performance problem, use a `for`.

Comment: Side note: Unless you're doing functional programming with predefined, reusable reducer functions, `reduce` is overcomplicated and easily messed up. Just use a loop.

Comment: 'Original object' as in if the filter string matches the name in a top level obejct, include all its children and create another object using the parent's properties. In the first example , since 'Foo' matches, we include all the children and create an object out of the two properties of the parent as well.

Comment: @MisterJojo: I was assuming that was intentional, that the output would be an array of objects with `name` and `value` properties.

Comment: @ScottSauyet guesses seldom allow correct programs

Comment: @MisterJojo: true, but neither do assumptions about errors.  :-).  Note that my guess matches two separate transformations: `{id, name} => {value, label}` and `{value, displayValue} => {value, label}`.  But you're right that it's only a guess.

Comment: The result will be an array of objects. Each object will have a label and a value key. I use ‘displayValue’ as label when using a nested type and ‘name’ as the label when picking up the parent object. For ‘value’ I use ‘value’ from a nested type and ‘Id’ if using the parent object.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one approach.  I break the problem down into helper/utility functions.

The logic is not much different from yours, although the breakdown is different.  The largest difference is that I use a `filterMap` implementation which filters and maps in a single pass.  I also use a `flatMap` on the top level rather than a `reduce`.  It seems simpler.

Here's my version:

```js
// utility function
const filterMap = (f, m) => (xs) =>
  xs .flatMap (x => f (x) ? [m (x)] : [])

// helper functions
const extractRoot = (_, id, name, nested) => [
  {label: name, value: id},
  ... nested .map (({value, displayValue}) => ({label: displayValue, value}))
]

const extractNested = (str, id, name, nested) => {
  const results = filterMap (
    ({displayValue}) => displayValue === str,
    ({displayValue, value}) => ({label: displayValue, value})
  ) (nested)
  return results.length ? [{label: name, value: id}, ...results] : []
}

// main function
const extract = (str, xs) =>
  xs .flatMap (({id, name, nestedTypes}) => 
    (name == str ? extractRoot : extractNested) (str, id, name, nestedTypes)
  )

// sample data
const data = [{id: '9', name: 'Foo', nestedTypes: [{value: '10025', displayValue: 'Request value A'}, {value: '10027', displayValue: 'Some random request'}]}, {id: '3', name: 'Name B', nestedTypes: [{displayValue: 'Bar', value: '10026', }, {displayValue: 'Another request within B'}]}]

// demo
console .log (extract ('Foo', data))
console .log (extract ('Bar', data))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

I guess there is one other difference.  In yours, if "Foo" matched at *both* levels, you would include the children twice, right?  I assume that's not what's wanted, but if it is, this code would need some changes.